# InputMethodManager: IME died: App freezed when fast-typing on EditText

Tags: android, performance, accessibilityservice

I'm trying to get all text from windows screen using `Accessibility Service`. Everything works but when I type on `EditText` fast, app and keyboard become freezed in few seconds. It's very strange because it only happens with all `EditText` in my app while other apps did not.

This is my code. I catch every event and use recursive call to get text deeply inside `AccessibilityNodeInfo`. Thanks!

```
public class WebAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService {
....

    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(final AccessibilityEvent event) {

   CharSequence eventPackageName = event.getPackageName();
        if (eventPackageName != null) {
            if (eventPackageName.equals(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID))    return;
            int eventType = event.getEventType();
            if (eventType == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED || eventType == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED) {
                AccessibilityNodeInfo mNodeInfo = event.getSource();
                String value = getAllTextViews(mNodeInfo); //When I remove this line, app does not freeze anymore.
            }
        }
    }

   private String getAllTextViews(AccessibilityNodeInfo nodeInfo){
        if (nodeInfo == null) return "";
        StringBuilder val = new StringBuilder();

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(nodeInfo.getText())) {
            val.append(nodeInfo.getText());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeInfo.getChildCount(); i++) {
            String v = getAllTextViews(nodeInfo.getChild(i));
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(v))
                val.append(v).append(" ");
        }
        return val.toString().replace('\n', ' ').replaceAll(" +", " ");
    }
}
```

And the logcat

```
09-01 16:09:22.197 30797-30797/com.androidapp.watchme D/detect===: EventType=TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED, package=com.sec.android.inputmethod
09-01 16:09:22.207 30797-30797/com.androidapp.watchme D/ViewRootImpl@aa32041[SettingsActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
09-01 16:09:22.236 30797-30797/com.androidapp.watchme D/ViewRootImpl@aa32041[SettingsActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
09-01 16:09:22.239 30797-30797/com.androidapp.watchme D/ViewRootImpl@aa32041[SettingsActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
09-01 16:09:22.249 30797-30797/com.androidapp.watchme D/ViewRootImpl@aa32041[SettingsActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
09-01 16:09:22.251 30797-30797/com.androidapp.watchme D/ViewRootImpl@aa32041[SettingsActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
09-01 16:09:22.256 30797-30797/com.androidapp.watchme D/ViewRootImpl@aa32041[SettingsActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
09-01 16:09:22.262 30797-30797/com.androidapp.watchme D/detect===: EventType=TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED, package=com.sec.android.inputmethod
09-01 16:09:22.265 30797-30797/com.androidapp.watchme I/Choreographer: Skipped 303 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-01 16:09:22.274 30797-30797/com.androidapp.watchme W/IInputConnectionWrapper: Got RemoteException calling setTextBeforeCursor
    android.os.DeadObjectException
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:761)
        at com.android.internal.view.IInputContextCallback$Stub$Proxy.setTextBeforeCursor(IInputContextCallback.java:169)
        at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:266)
        at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:85)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
09-01 16:09:22.280 30797-30797/com.androidapp.watchme V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@f20b6c9 nm : com.androidapp.watchme ic=com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection@11541ce
09-01 16:09:22.287 30797-30797/com.androidapp.watchme W/InputMethodManager: IME died: com.sec.android.inputmethod/.SamsungKeypad
    android.os.DeadObjectException
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:761)
        at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodSession$Stub$Proxy.updateSelection(IInputMethodSession.java:228)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.updateSelection(InputMethodManager.java:2190)
        at android.widget.Editor.sendUpdateSelection(Editor.java:1705)
        at android.widget.Editor.finishBatchEdit(Editor.java:1550)
        at android.widget.Editor.endBatchEdit(Editor.java:1524)
        at android.widget.TextView.endBatchEdit(TextView.java:8799)
        at com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection.endBatchEdit(EditableInputConnection.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.finishComposingText(BaseInputConnection.java:444)
        at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.closeConnection(BaseInputConnection.java:163)
        at com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection.closeConnection(EditableInputConnection.java:88)
        at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:541)
        at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.dispatchMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:225)
        at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.closeConnection(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:211)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ControlledInputConnectionWrapper.deactivate(InputMethodManager.java:644)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.startInputInner(InputMethodManager.java:1725)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$H.handleMessage(InputMethodManager.java:566)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
09-01 16:09:22.288 30797-30797/com.androidapp.watchme I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, the first thing I noticed is that this is a Samsung device.

> 09-01 16:09:22.287 30797-30797/com.androidapp.watchme W/InputMethodManager: IME died: com.sec.android.inputmethod/.SamsungKeypad

Have you tried to replicate this behavior on a Pixel or Nexus device?

Comment: Yes, i did. It also happen with other device, and any Keyboard application.